# Change Frame Size on OpenCV JavaCameraView

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, frame

I'm creating an application on Android that is using OpenCV's JavaCameraView. I'm trying to change the returned frame size but changing the frame still returns frames at 320X240.

```
@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(480, 640, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mGray = new Mat(480, 640, CvType.CV_8UC4);
}


@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
    inputFrame.copyTo(mRgba);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

    // Processing

    return mRgba;
}
```

Any help on how to change the returned frame size would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could change the max frame size of your JavaCameraView with [setMaxFrameSize](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.8/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.html#setMaxFrameSize(int,%20int)).

> When selecting size - the biggest size which less or equal the size set will be selected. As an example - we set setMaxFrameSize(200,200) and we have 176x152 and 320x240 sizes. The preview frame will be selected with 176x152 size.